# Why are strings declared as an array "char word[5] = "hello" modifiable but not strings declared as pointer (char *word = "hello")?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I was under the impression that

```
    char word[5] = "hello";
```

is the same as

```
    char *word = "hello";
```

because arrays always decay into a pointer?

Comment: `char word[5] = "hello";` can't be treated as a string, it's a normal character array. `word` needs to have space for 6 characters to make it a proper C string (The trailing 0 is critical).

Comment: `char* word = "hello"` gets compiled into a different read-only section of your program - here's an answer that goes into more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589963/1158478

Answer (score 0):

`char *word = "hello";`  Takes the address of a string literal.  These are often held in read-only memory.